# How do I test for the appearance of a DOM node using react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm in the process of moving over to react-testing-library, and am having trouble asserting that the text changes given some state. What I want to test for is the appearance of the "Second option selected" text or node. But this just fails since the node doesn't change. It works in the browser though.

I've looked at the [docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-disappearance), but using `wait` or `waitForElement` isn't working for me for some reason.

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const options = {
  First: "First",
  Second: "Second"
};

function App() {
  const [action, setAction] = useState(options.First);

  return (
    <form>
      <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="radio1"
          value={options.First}
          checked={action === options.First}
          onChange={event => setAction(event.target.value)}
        />
        First
      </label>

      <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="radio1"
          value={options.Second}
          checked={action === options.Second}
          onChange={event => setAction(event.target.value)}
        />
        Second
      </label>

      {action === options.First ? (
        <div>First option selected</div>
      ) : action === options.Second ? (
        <div>Second option selected</div>
      ) : null}

    </form>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**App.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, cleanup, fireEvent } from 'react-testing-library';
import App from './App';

afterEach(cleanup);

it('radio button', async () => {
  const {getByLabelText, getByText } = render(<App/>);
  const first = getByLabelText("First");

  fireEvent.change(first, { target: { value: "Second" }});

  expect(first.value).toEqual("Second");
  expect(getByText("Second option selected").textContent).toEqual("Second option selected") ;

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This test works:

```
it("radio button", () => {
  const { getByLabelText, getByText } = render(<App />);

  fireEvent.click(getByLabelText("Second"));

  /* This will fail
     expect(getByLabelText("First").value).toEqual("Second");
  */
  expect(getByText("Second option selected")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

I think there's some weird behavior in jsdom that for some reason fires the 'onChange' event only if a `click` happens. At the same time, it doesn't update the `value` in the DOM unless a `change` event happens.

My advice is not to check the `value` of your radio inputs. In the end, your test should only care about what the user sees.